# How would you describe both "XX is the furthest I have traveled" and "XX is my favorite place?"

Tags: english-to-japanese

Now actually I already wrote both of these lines as so:

> カナダは私の家族が一番遠い場所でした。

and

> マクドナルドは私の場所一番好きです。

I want to say `Canada is the furthest my family has traveled` and `McDonalds is my favorite place.`

The thing is, I'm being told that the structure of these two sentences is incorrect, but I'm having trouble finding out what is incorrect about these, I was wondering if anyone here knows what the more "correct" way to say these two sentences in Japanese.

Comment: your first sentence is missing a verb, first of all... the way it's written it sounds like "As for Canada, my family was the furthest place." Your second sentence sounds like "McDonald's is my place favorite." I need to get out the door now or I would help more, sorry.

Comment: Do you mean that McDonalds is your favorite place in general? Or McDonalds was your favorite place when you and your family went to Canada?

Comment: I just mean in general, but for some reason one of my assistants is telling me that the `私の場所一番好き` - part isn't correct.

Comment: 私の一番好きな場所, not 私の場所一番好き/